# How can I create a frozen inference graph from just the savedmodel.pb? I do not have any checkpoint files

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-automl

I have exported my model from Google AutoML image classification. I only have a saved_model.pb and no checkpoint or metafiles. Is there a way to convert this saved_model.pb to frozen_inferenc_graph

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following method with only .pb file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

GRAPH_PB_PATH = './model/model_file.pb' #path to your .pb file
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
  print("load graph")
  with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    sess.graph.as_default()
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
```

Now when you freeze a graph to **.pb** file your variables are converted to Const type and the weights which were trainable variables would also be stored as Const in .pb file. graph_nodes contains all the nodes in the graph. But we are interested in all the Const type nodes.

```
wts = [n for n in graph_nodes if n.op=='Const']
```

Each element of wts is of NodeDef type. It has several attributes such as name, op etc. The values can be extracted as follows -

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

for n in wts:
    print "Name of the node - %s" % n.name
    print "Value - " 
    print tensor_util.MakeNdarray(n.attr['value'].tensor)
```

Hope this solves your concern.

Comment: @Amudha Sethuraman -Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.